# Invalid literal for int() with base 10 in template with multiple forms

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I have a form that only links to one of the fields in one of my models. I'm trying to save the form, but I keep getting errors and don't know what to change.

Models.py

```
class FunctionManager(models.Manager):
def editover(self, Function_id, postData):
    woo = Function.objects.get(id=Function_id)
    woo.new = postData["new"]
    woo.save()

class Function(models.Model):
tableA = models.CharField(max_length=50)
new = models.TextField()
def __str__(self):
    return str (self.tableA, self.id)
objects = FunctionManager()
```

views.py

```
def function_page(request, Function_id):
assignments = Function.objects.get(id=Function_id)
context = {
    'assignments': assignments,
}
return render (request, 'project/function.html', context)


def new_save(request, Function_id):
newest = Function.objects.editover('Function_id', request.POST['new'])
return redirect ('project/function.html')
```

urls.py

```
 url(r'^function_page/(?P<Function_id>\d+)$', views.function_page, name "function_page"),
 url(r'^new_save/(?P<Function_id>\d+)/$', views.new_save, name = "new_save")
```

html

```
  <div id=new>
    <form action= "/SCS/new/{{assignments.id}}/"  method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
      <textarea name="new" id="Obox"></textarea>
      <input class="save" type="submit" value="Save">
    </form>
  </div>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing a string into the `FunctionManager.editover` method for the Function_id arg, however it should be an integer because that variable is being used in a `Model.objects.get(id=Function_id)` call.

```
newest = WarFightingFunction.objects.editover('Function_id', request.POST['new'])
```

Is calling:

```
class FunctionManager(models.Manager):
    def editover(self, Function_id, postData):
        woo = Function.objects.get(id=Function_id)
        woo.new = postData["new"]
        woo.save()
```

And passing the "Function_id" string literal into the `Function.objects.get(id=Function_id)`